# Python xpath capturing all <tr> and looping through them accessing sub xpath

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to loop through all `<tr>` elements, pass them to a `for` loop and access child data contained in `th`

Only it looks like the `data_template` in below example is empty and the loop is not accessed

## question

how can I grab all `<tr>` nodes and then loop through them accessing sub xpath for `<th>`?

## code

```
    data_template = response.xpath('//div[@id="product-options-wrapper"]/table/thead/tr')
    print('before loop')
    for i, data_row in enumerate(data_template):
        print('start of datarow')
        if i == 0:
            print('1st data row')
            sizes = data_row.xpath('/th').getall()
            continue
        else:
            print('2nd datarow')
```

## Example data

[image]

## On page

[image]

## Python code

```
    def parse_list(self, response):
        for url in response.xpath('.//div[@itemprop="itemListElement"]/a/@href').getall():
            yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_detail, meta=response.meta)
    
    def parse_detail(self, response):
        item = DynamicItem()
        item['meta'] = response.meta
        item['url'] = response.url
        print(item['url']) # Works fine
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()').get()
        print(item['name']) # Strange keeps giving the same name after url 1, so for url 2 and for 3 etc
        data_template = response.xpath('//div[@id="product-options-wrapper"]/table/thead/tr')
        print(data_template) # Empty? But there should be 3 results!!
```

Comment: How do you obtain this `response`? What is it built from?

Comment: 'yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_detail, meta=response.meta)` returns the request url and calls callback = parse_detail. Correct? ... also when printing response.url we can see it is populated

Comment: I mean, how do you get the HTML to parse? Is it with something like python-requests?

Comment: if I call yield Request with a call back, then the html is stored in `response` correct? I mean `item['name'] = response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()').get()` for example works fine for every url ...

Comment: Strange .... `//div[@id="product-options-wrapper"]` is found ... but `//div[@id="product-options-wrapper"]/table` is not ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A XPath is like a UNIX path. "./" refers to current node as current directory in UNIX.

```
data_row.xpath('./th').getall()
```

Comment: thx ;) The problem seems to be `data_template ` is empty ...if I use print(data_template ) the result is []

Comment: @snh_nl the screenshot given doesn't show the `<div>` you're mentioning though. Could you take a larger snippet of the HTML code? Also, does searching for a prefix work? i.e. does only calling `xpath('//div[@id="product-options-wrapper"]')` return anything?

Comment: Updated original img .... and believe me there are more `trs` below ;)

Comment: Does searching for a prefix work? i.e. does only calling `.xpath('//div[@id="product-options-wrapper"]')` return anything?

Comment: I solved it using `response.xpath('//div[@id="product-options-wrapper"]//thead/tr')` which works but `response.xpath('//div[@id="product-options-wrapper"]/table/thead/tr')` does not ..... no no idea why ... just cost me 3 hours of my life